# View number of readers on Tumblr blog

Tags: tumblr, blog

I am new to Tumblr and don't know how to tell if someone has read my blog, or how many. How can I see this info?

Answer (score 4):

Tumblr doesn't offer any statistics by default. However, you can edit your theme and add in a tracking service's code that will allow you to see how many people have visited your blog (this would also include your own visits).

[Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics) is the easiest way to get started and it's free.

To get to your theme editor you'll need to go to `http://www.tumblr.com/customize/<blogname>` and click on `Edit HTML` to paste in the code that Google Analytics gives you.